# Redirect to same view with different arguments

Tags: python, django, redirect, apache

I have this setup:

**urls.py**

```
url(r"^(?P<id1>\d+)/(?P<id2>\d+)/$", "project.views.view", name="view"),
```

**matching views.py**

```
def view(request, id1, id2):
    if request.method == "POST":
        """a lot of processing"""
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view', args=(id1, different_id2)))
```

Unfortunately when this happens it actually resolved as:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view', args=(id1, id2)))
```

So I get the same page as the post was submitted from.

Is this a problem? Calling redirect to same view, but with different arguments.

(I removed original names -- it would be too confusing)

Comment: No, what you describe doesn't happen. There is something in your "a lot of processing" which means that `different_id2` isn't what you think it is, and is somehow set to equal `id2`.

Comment: Actually it is, because I'm printing URL gotten from reverse and the URL is correct, response isn't.

Answer (score 2):

No, that should work. There's likely a bug in your code setting the id's, or returning the `HttpResponseRedirect` too early. Drop into the debugger and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. You were right.

The problem was that I have helper function (splitting view into smaller pieces) and forgot to add return for the helper:

```
def helper(request, id1, id2):
    """a lot of processing"""
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view', args=(id1, different_id2)))

def view(request, id1, id2):
    if request.method == "POST":
        helper(request, ...)
    """process get"""
```

should be

```
def view(request, id1, id2):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return helper(request, ...)
    """process get"""
```